# Как вытянуть вложенный div по высоте родителя с учетом других div?

Tags: css3, html, вёрстка, css

Есть `div`, в который столбиком вложены три `div`. Первые два имеют фиксированную высоту, последний должен зависеть от остатка высоты родительского `div`.

Этот же последний `div` содержит большую простыню текста, которая должна прокручиваться в нем.

Проблема в том, что последний `div` c `height:100%` равняется высоте родительского блока и не учитывает высоту его "братьев", а без `height:100%` равняется высоте вложенного в него текста.

Вопрос: можно ли средствами СSS заставить этот `div` равняться остатку высоты родителя.

Comment: на крайний случай в css3 есть calc

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8e3d1op4/

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}


.table{    
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}
.table-row{
    display: table-row;
    border: 1px solid #000;    
}
.table-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #000;   
    padding: 10px;    
}
.table-cell1{
    height: 100px;    
}

.text{
    max-height: 100px; 
    overflow: auto;
}

.text2{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
   
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell table-cell1">
              <div class="text"> Есть div, в который столбиком вложены три div. Первые два имеют фиксированную высоту, последний должен зависеть от остатка высоты родительского div.

Этот же последний div содержит большую простыню текста, которая должна прокручиваться в нем.

Проблема в том, что последний div c height:100% равняется высоте родительского блока и не учитывает высоту его "братьев", а без height:100% равняется высоте вложенного в него текста.

Вопрос: можно ли средствами СSS заставить этот div равняться остатку высоты родителя.
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell table-cell1">
              <div class="text"> Есть div, в который столбиком вложены три div. Первые два имеют фиксированную высоту, последний должен зависеть от остатка высоты родительского div.

Этот же последний div содержит большую простыню текста, которая должна прокручиваться в нем.

Проблема в том, что последний div c height:100% равняется высоте родительского блока и не учитывает высоту его "братьев", а без height:100% равняется высоте вложенного в него текста.

Вопрос: можно ли средствами СSS заставить этот div равняться остатку высоты родителя.
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell table-cell2">
            <div class="text2">
                This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.This CSS module defines a scripting interface to font faces in CSS, allowing font faces to be easily created and loaded from script. It also provides methods to track the loading status of an individual font, or of all the fonts on an entire page.
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```